# How do I determine which Single Variable Discrete Model is appropriate to use?

Tags: statistics, random-variables

I am taking a statistics course and we are studying Random Variables and Probability Models right now.
I am learning a lot about the probability functions for different variables, but I am having a really hard time determining which model to use for any given question that is assigned.
We have covered:

- Discrete Uniform
- Hypegeometric
- Binomial
- Negative Binomial
- Geometric
- Poisson

Does any one have any tips on knowing which one is appropriate to use in which situations?

Comment: Welcome to MSE @TopGunCpp.  It will help us answer your questions if you narrow it down a bit - this is pretty broad.  Do you have examples of different situations for which you are confused about which probability function to use?

Comment: Unfortunately you are right, the question is quite broad. As I have been studying the content I notice that I deduce to use one method but it always seems like I make the wrong assumptions. I thought it might be beneficial to ask just in general, although I see my error now in asking such a broad question. Sorry about that :\

Comment: No problem @TopGunCpp.  Feel free to edit the question if you think of something.

Comment: Dont apologize. You asked a question about concept. Abstract. They are broad by default.  I respect you a hell of a lot more than the person who asks a specific question that they drew from their evening homework. And I lose respect for anyone who mocks you for asking a question that demands conceptual explanation, because if doing that is too difficult for them then they probably dont understand the material as well as they want to get credit for.